# How to capture image with camera and store it in a seperate folder

Tags: android, gridview, gallery

scene 1: I am having a task in android to capture image from its camera and store the captured  image it in a separate folder,

- scene1 i am now able to do now(means captured image is storing in my 
  customized folder(example folder name john)).
- scene 2: Next task is  to show all the captured image of my app in a
  grid format having check box for selection of a images(just like
  whats app does for image selection)
- scene 2 i am able to do this from a good example to image in a grid
  view  like a android album gallery ,with a check box , but the thing
  is that ,  the gallery is not showing my customized image folder and
  its images where i have captured all the images from the app

please help me regarding this issue
Thanks in advance

Comment: The galery is not showing your images. But why do you care? Your app should show your images! What has your app to do with the Gallery app? You know 'the gallery' is just an app? You do not know that the gallery app will show your images once you reboot your device? The subject of your post is completely wrong. Please change to a better one.

Comment: ...and what is your question now about programming??? you must ask a question consequently. paste some code and show the parts which make problems.